# sink vs console output---what is the opposite of message()?

Tags: r

I am trying to take full control of output to both the console and the (split) sink file.  For one, I want certain output to be colored on the [ansi] console but not clutter up my Rout file.

I know of two basic commands:

- `cat()` outputs to both the console and the sink file.
- `message()` outputs only to the console (via file stderr), but not to the sink file.

I start with

```
messageln <- function(...) {
    boldblue <- "\033[34;1m"; ansioff <- "\033[0m"
    if (interactive()) message(boldblue)  # fails.  stderr dest overrides
    cat(..., sep="")
    if (interactive()) message(ansioff)   # fails.  stderr dest overrides
}
```

1. Problem 1: the ansi terminal command is emitted and interpreted by my console only if I use `cat` instead of `message`.  this is presumably because message emits its own ansi-off to turn off coloring.
2. Problem 2: is there an opposite to `message()` that outputs a string only to the sink file but not to the console?

Comment: Can't you use `sink`?

Comment: good question, not easily.  I already have turned on the sink file with a `split=T`.  I guess one way would be to turn off sink(), reopen-append() the sinkfile but not with split, print what I want to print, close the sinkfile, and reopen with split and append.  this may be the best choice...